# XCode 4.5 - Indent code to the left

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5

I am using XCode 4.5 and I need to indent about 50 lines of code to the left by 1-tab. How can I do this (without doing it line by line) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Cmd-[. That will indent the selected lines by one tab to the left. You can find the menu commend in Editor->Structure->Shift Left

Comment: I need to indent in the opposite direction

Answer (score 2):

Select all of the text and press Option + ] to shift right or Option + [ to shift left.